# How do I determine list of valid events for current state

Tags: spring-statemachine

When represeting a statemachine in UI it will be useful to know the list of valid events for the current state in order to disable/hide invalid options.
I would not want to replicate all statemachine rules.

Answer (score 0):

We have had this issue [gh-44](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/44) open a long time but I haven't found any reliable way to look into a future and predict what a machine would do.

Problem comes from a fact that with nested hierarchical states, same event can be handled by any state starting from active one into its parent structure. As transition(s) can have `Guards` which may evaluate conditions dynamically, even if we'd add some sort of a prediction engine, it would still be impossible to predict future as we don't have a time machine.